# chicken and egg Spring bean binding

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Ok, so here is my use case:

I have the following classes each encapsulating an instance of the next one in line. So:

A -> B -> C -> D

eg: In class A, I have an instance of class B and in class B I have an instance of C and so on.

Well, I am trying to convert the loading\initialization\injection logic to a hybrid Spring system. The general idea being that B, C and D will need to more or less be `ApplicationContextAware`. By that I mean, that they will not actually implement that interface, but instead require the `ApplicationContext` as a constructor parameter. This way, in the hybrid approach (where the developer does not use Spring to initialize the instance) they must at least pass in the `ApplicationContext` so that additional beans may be wired. The problem is, that in order for the Spring container to load the beans, I now have to pass in the `ApplicationContext` in the XML. But as far as I can tell, there is no nice way to do this.

I tried something like this:

```
public class ApplicationContextPlaceholder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext _applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext( final ApplicationContext applicationContext ) throws BeansException {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return _applicationContext;
    }

}

<bean id="a" class="com.company.A">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="applicationContext" class="com.company.ApplicationContextPlaceholder" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But obviously this doesn't make any sense, since `ApplicationContextPlaceholder` isn't *really* an `ApplicationContext`. I've also looked for ways to reference the context inside the XML, but I'm not finding anything.

Does anyone know of an elegant solution to this type of problem?

**EDIT #1:**

I was thinking about it, and I could have `ApplicationContextPlaceholder` also implement `ApplicationContext` and just delegate to the injected context and then it occurred to me that maybe, just maybe this was already in Spring...but as far as I can tell, no.

**EDIT #2:**

The reason each class needs an `ApplicationContext` is that if a dev wishes to override one of the classes in the chain (say, C for sake of argument). In this instance the child class of C will still need to load D via Spring.

Comment: Do you absolutely need the `ApplicationContext` in your constructor?  You should be able to just autowire it if you do not.

Comment: Yes, each instance needs the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: It would help if you could explain the intention behind having such many heavyweight classes (i.e. essentially being ApplicationContextAware) in a row

Comment: @DanielDinnyes - I will edit it to fill in what you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a class is providing additional plumbing functionality, you should avoid exposing the `ApplicationContext`. Quoting the Spring reference: [`in general you should avoid it, because it couples the code to Spring and does not follow the Inversion of Control style`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-aware).

If you are providing additional functionality (maybe, for example, a factory class that uses the `ApplicationContext` to assemble objects), then it's prudent to implement `ApplicationContextAware` since your functionality is already tied to Spring.

If you've considered your [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) alternatives and have decided on injecting the `ApplicationContext` in your beans, your `ApplicationContextPlaceholder` class (I would stay away from a `Placeholder` prefix to avoid any confusion with Spring [property placeholders](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)) is certainly a solution. (Since it is your own class, why not extend [`ApplicationObjectSupport`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ApplicationObjectSupport.html) for additional functionality.)

This class will need to be defined and initialized in your configuration, for example:

```
<bean id="appCtxHolder" class="ApplicationContextHolder" />
```

Because `ApplicationContextHolder` implements `ApplicationContextAware`, Spring will inject the `ApplicationContext` into `appCtxHolder` when it is initialized. You can use it for constructor injection like:

```
<bean id="a" class="com.company.A">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean factory-bean="appCtxHolder" factory-method="getApplicationContext" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: That's alot to think about, thanks for the information +1. I do think that I need the context all the way down in each in class. I do realize that this creates a tight coupling with Spring, however, this particular project is an amalgamation of Spring and our business logic, so given that it might be ok. I'll weigh my options and check back, so far this is the closest answer I've got to accepting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationContextPlaceholder` could have everything static. In that case, you don't need to pass `ApplicationContext` around, when a API requests for a certain bean, you could check if its null and if it is, load it using the `ApplicationContext` from `ApplicationContextPlaceholder`. That's assuming a setter based injection, if you are doing constructor based, you could init beans in the contructor too.